# How do I access the previous state in react hooks which the state is a string value

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble accessing the previous state which is a string value.

```
    const [seat, selectSeat] = useState("");
```

I tried to use useRef, which is used to get the previous state of an integer value.

```
const prevSeatRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
    prevSeatRef.current = seat;
    console.log(seat , prevSeatRef.current);
  },[seat]); 

function currentSeatSelected() {
    if(prevSeatRef.current === ""){
        document.getElementById(seat).classList.add("selected");
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(prevSeatRef.current).classList.remove("selected");
        document.getElementById(seat).classList.add("selected");
    }
}
```

However, this method when console logged, shows two same states. How can I fix this, or are there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `useRef` hook allows you to persist values between renders and accessing real DOM elements.

So, you can define another state and store the previous value. Then, in an event like clicking or etc., check the current and previous values.

Comment: so should I store the prevSeatRef.current in another state like this?         selectPrevSeat(prevSeatRef.current);

Comment: You don't need `useRef` at all. Forget it. Set a state in the `useEffect` above and check for the existing to keep the previous state stable.

Comment: This did work in a way that when I console logged the seat and prevSeat inside the useEffect it logged the correctly. However, when I tried to use it inside the function above, it did not work as I expected(when i click on a div the currentSeatSelected function is called and the clicked div will have the class "selected" and the previous div will lose the class "selected".). Sorry for the inconvenience, but do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: When I tried to console log the seat and prevSeat inside the function whenever they try to add the class "selected" it logged the same value. Ex) a1 a1